# How to put a validation on Google Spreadsheet cell to accept only 10 digit comma separated numbers?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-sheets-api

I can use "=AND(ISNUMBER($B2),LEN($B2)=10)", but it restricts me to input only a Single 10 digit number. My requirement is to accept either 1 or N 10 digit comma separated numbers(based on user).
Ex: "1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,n..."

Let's say A person can have 2 contact numbers, I just want to restrict the cell to accept only 10 digit comma separated number.

Can it be done directly on Google Sheet? or if there is some other way to achieve it. Please help me out.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8XjW.png)

Comment: Not sure - but I think I'd be looking at Google App Scripts based on JavaScript. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview. You might find a library that has such functionality already built. Perhaps others can add their two-cents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
=REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(A2),"^(\d{10})(,\d{10})*$")
```

Cell range:

```
A2:A
```

- A2:A needs to be formatted as TEXT.
- The expression matches 10 `\d`igits and zero or more of `,` followed 10 `\d`igits.

Comment: Thanks, i have converted numbers to plaintext & It works!

Comment: Hey, Is it possible to put a validation like, if Column A contains 2 ","(comma separated) Names then Column B will contain 2, 10 digit numbers?  If A contain 1 name then B will contain only 1 10 digit number.

Comment: @Dhiraj Yes.But that's a different q. it's better to ask in a different thread along with your efforts so far.